# Select Group name by its content in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table where I want to get GroupName having exact Variants in the table

```
    +-----------+-----------+
    | GroupName | VariantID |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_1_4 |     1     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_1_4 |     2     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_1_4 |     3     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_1_4 |     4     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_5_2 |     2     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_5_2 |     3     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_7_3 |     1     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_7_3 |     2     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |GRP724_7_3 |     3     |
    +-----------+-----------+
```

I want to search group name who have exact those variants like if I search for VariantID "2","3" then result should be "GRP724_5_2" because it have exact "2,3".
So if I search for Variant ID "1,2,3" then result should be "GRP724_7_3".

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select groupname
from t
group by groupname
having sum(case when variantid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when variantid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when variantid not in (2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you want to pass the value in as a string, then use `string_split()` or a similar function to convert the string to a table.  Assuming no duplicates in the string or the original table:

```
with v as (
      select convert(int, value) as variantid
      from string_split(@s) s
     )
select t.groupname
from t left join
     v
     on t.variantid = v.variantid
group by t.groupname
having count(*) = (select count(*) from v) and
       count(*) = count(variantid);
```

You can handle duplicates with judicious use of `count(distinct)`.